# Drag it, drop it and drag it again by dropping back to original position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to get help on the following situation.

I have two columns, one contains numbers and other is to receive them by drag and drop.

Left column is draggable and right column is droppable.
I would like to make the right column draggable as well, so if the users change their mind, they can drag and drop it back to the left column and start again.

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
  revert: true
});

$('.droppable').droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    $(this).html(ui.draggable.html());
    $(ui.draggable).html('');
  }
});
```

[image: The issue]

Please see jsfiddle link: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidthesimon/dt3q0hfa/)

Comment: Just make all of the divs both `draggable` and `droppable`. It seems to work just fine unless there's a more specific issue.

Comment: If I do that, after dropping to the right column and dragging again, I cannot drop it back nor to the same position neither to the original position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make functions that you can pass object to to enable drag and drop. In this way it makes it easy to make one dragged item draggable again and it's source droppable, etc.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/nuopmqnb/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  function makeDrag($o) {
    $o.draggable({
      revert: true,
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        if (!$(this).find("img").size()) {
          $(this)
            .removeClass("draggable")
            .addClass("droppable")
            .draggable("destroy");
          makeDrop($(this));
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function makeDrop($o) {
    $o.droppable({
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        var $img = $("<img>", {
            src: ui.draggable.find("img").attr("src")
          }),
          $target = $(e.target);
        ui.draggable.html("");
        $target.html($img);
        $target.droppable("destroy");
        makeDrag($target);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  makeDrag($('.draggable'));
  makeDrop($('.droppable'));
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to achieve! Thanks for your help!
Meanwhile I made another solution, but it was buggy a bit and this one works without a doubt.